# How would I get files deleted from source before all files are finished copying?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, download, rsync

## Background

I'm using rsync to download a whole bunch of large files, from a webserver to my local machine (running rsync off the local machine).
On the webserver end, it is important that these files be deleted once downloaded to indicate to the server that they have been downloaded.

## Scenario

Using the command:
`rsync -e ssh -r --bwlimit=32 --remove-source-files --update --partial-dir /home/me/.rsync-partial remote_host:/home/me/folder-of-big-files /home/me/local-store-for-big-files`
for a test with not very many files, it worked great and as expected.
I had the files downloaded, and they were deleted from the remote server and all was well.

Moving up to full-scale downloads though, I've noticed that despite there being files from the server available to me locally, they aren't being deleted from the server.
I assume this is because rsync `lists all files, then downloads all files, then deletes all files` rather than `lists all files, then downloads a file, then deletes that file, then repeats till the list is empty`

## Problem

Due to being Australian, I have to limit my download speed so that I don't run out of data.
This means that the amount of time it takes to reach the `delete files` section of processing is always longer than the amount of time it takes to reach the `something went wrong and rsync didn't complete` stage.

This means, whatever files *were* downloaded successfully, aren't deleted from the server.
However, since they've already been downloaded, my understanding is that they aren't deleted from the remote sever the next time rsync executes either.

## Query

Is there any better way to get the files deleted sooner after they have been downloaded?
I'm considering listing the directories, and separately rsyncing within subdirectories on files only, but am open to better alternatives.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I assume this is because rsync `lists all files, then downloads all files, then deletes all files`

This is exactly what the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) says (my emphasis)

> --remove-source-files
>
> This tells rsync to remove from the sending side the files (meaning non-directories) **that are a part of the transfer** and have been successfully duplicated on the receiving side.

So files are removed only after **all** files **that are part of the transfer** are transferred successfully. Even if 99% are transferred it isn't going to delete them until the last 1% is.

> I'm considering listing the directories, and separately rsyncing within subdirectories on files only

You could do that and when each individual *rsync* completed it would delete file(s) on source.  You'd need to consider if the group of files you are downloading are part of a coherent whole though.  You say

> On the webserver end, it is important that these files be deleted once downloaded to indicate to the server that they have been downloaded.

What happens if your new download script only successfully downloads and deletes half the files?  Will the webserver overwrite *everything* so you miss some files?  Or will it replace each individual file only when it is deleted and keep appending data to existing ones until it is?

It may not matter in your case but often you want groups of files in a consistent state so it is worth considering. You don't want to download and delete the *"Today's Orders"* file if it means the server will overwrite "*Today's Delivery Addresses"* and you don't have it...

Comment: It doesn't matter in my case, each file is only important individually.   
They also don't change once they're made available.  
The importance of removal from the remote source is mainly related to available space, and trace-ability of individual files.

My thinking is to somehow remotely list at a directory level, and then loop and parametise rsync so it works on the lowest hierarchical level only, but not entirely sure how I'd do that.